# Network IsAlive Issue C#

Tags: c#

Currently I am programming a simple chat. For the network I use a network watcher, which reads from the stream and also writes to it. For safety reasons I want to implement an is alive check where in a special time interval the client sends a message to the server and the server sends a message to the client. The method for that is called "IsAliveWorker" which runs in an own thread. But I have problems with timing the check if the other side received the message. After some time it always fires the ConnectionLostEvent which should only be fired when the client or the server disconnects without notifying the other side before (For example when the User kills the process or computer shut down). I don't really know whats the problem here but I am thinking it is a timing issue. The code below is from the client side but the IsAliveWorker method is the same on the server, so I only posted it once. I would really appreciate if someone would check my code below, I am messing around with it for a long while now. :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Client
{
    public class NetworkWatcher
    {
        private TcpClient client;
        private NetworkStream stream;
        private IPEndPoint ipEndPoint;
        private bool isReading;
        private Thread readThread;
        private Thread isAliveThread;
        private bool isAlive;

        public event EventHandler<DataReceivedEventArgs> DataReceived;
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ConnectionLost;

        public NetworkWatcher(IPAddress ip, int port)
        {
            this.ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
            this.client = new TcpClient();
        }

        public bool Connected
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            try
            {
                if (this.client.ConnectAsync(this.ipEndPoint.Address, this.ipEndPoint.Port).Wait(1000) == false)
                {
                    throw new TimeoutException();
                }

                this.stream = this.client.GetStream();

                this.readThread = new Thread(Read);
                this.isReading = true;
                this.readThread.Start();
                this.Connected = true;

                this.isAliveThread = new Thread(this.IsAliveWorker);
                this.isAliveThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
                this.isAliveThread.Start();
            }
            catch
            {
                this.FireOnConnectionLost();
            }
        }

        private void IsAliveWorker()
        {
            while (this.isReading == true)
            {
                this.Send(ProtocolCreator.IsAlive());

                Thread.Sleep(2000);

                if (this.isAlive == false)
                {
                    this.FireOnConnectionLost();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.isAlive = false;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            try
            {
                this.isReading = false;
                this.stream.Close();
                this.client.Close();
                this.client = new TcpClient();
                this.Connected = false;
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }

        private void Read()
        {
            while (this.isReading == true)
            {
                if (this.stream.DataAvailable == false)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                    continue;
                }

                List<byte> receivedBytes = new List<byte>();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1];

                while (this.stream.DataAvailable == true)
                {
                    this.stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1);

                    if (buffer[0] == 127)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    receivedBytes.Add(buffer[0]);
                }

                if (receivedBytes.Count >= 6)
                {
                    if (receivedBytes[0] == 67 && receivedBytes[1] == 72 && receivedBytes[2] == 65 && receivedBytes[3] == 84)
                    {
                        if (receivedBytes[4] == 73 && receivedBytes[5] == 65)
                        {
                            this.isAlive = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this.FireOnDataReceived(receivedBytes.ToArray());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected virtual void FireOnDataReceived(byte[] data)
        {
            if (this.DataReceived != null)
            {
                this.DataReceived(this, new DataReceivedEventArgs(data, this.client));
            }
        }

        protected virtual void FireOnConnectionLost()
        {
            if (this.ConnectionLost != null)
            {
                this.ConnectionLost(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }

        public void Send(Protocol protocol)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] sendBytes = protocol.ToByteArray();

                this.stream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
            }
            catch
            {
                this.FireOnConnectionLost();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wel, it's kinda usual to time out the connection at the server socket. If the server socket has not received anything for [poll interval] ms, it sets a 'polled' flag and sends a ping.  If another  [poll interval] passes with no receipt of data or gnip. the server assumes the client unreachable and closes its socket.   Such a scheme avoids sending polls when there is no need, ie. when data is already flowing successfully between client and server.

Comment: @MartinJames Thats the thing I do here. The client send messages to the server and the server sends messages to the client. After a special time interval they check if they received the message. If they didn't received it, they assume the connection was lost. But I think my IsAliveWorker method has a timing problem and after a time it thinks that one side disconnected, but it didn't.